# Jquery UI Clean transition between drop and showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm struggling a bit getting a webpage to smoothly take out buttons and replace them with different buttons. This is the code:

```
function expandDateSearch() {
      $("#button-search-by-date").toggle("drop");
      $("#search-tab-label").css("display","none");
      $("#button-search-by-keyword").toggle("drop");

      // Wait a half second before executing this
          setTimeout(function() {
              $( "#search-input-date" ).show( "fold", 100 );
              $("#date-search-button").show("fold",100);
              $("#button-search-reset").show("fold",100);
              $("#search-header").text("Search by Date");
          },400);
      }
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<!-- Search content goes here -->
                            <div>
                                <h4 id="accordion-search-text" class="accordion-header" style="display:none">Keyword:</h4>
                                <input type="text" id="accordion-search-input" style="display:none">
                                <h4 id="search-header">Search By: </h4>
                                <input type="button" value="Keyword" id="button-search-by-keyword" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:25px;float:left;"></input>
                                <h4 id="search-tab-label" style="float:left; margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;"> Or by </h4>
                                <input type="button" value="Date" id="button-search-by-date" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:15px;float:left;"></input>
                                <input type="text" value="Enter Date" id="search-input-date" style="display:none">
                                <input type="button" id="date-search-button" value="Search Date" style="display:none"></input>
                                <input type="button" value="Search" id="button-search" style="display:none;"/>
                                <input type="text" value="Enter Keyword" id="search-keyword-value" style="display:none;"></input>
                                <input type="button" value="Search Keyword" id="button-search-by-keyword-value" style="display:none;"></input>
                                <input type="button" id="button-search-reset" value="Restart Search" style="display:none;"></input>                         
                                <br>
                            </div>
```

As you can see this is very simple. The function expandDateSearch() takes three HTML elements and replaces them with four elements. I used the setTimeout because it looks even worse when it all executes at once. I feel it would be better if there was a function that you fed a list of HTML elements to remove with animation as the first argument and a list of things to show as the second argument but I'm not seeing that in Jquery UI documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to encapsulate each of the HTML elements in its own div then float:left.